# Convertir una lista de String a una lista de lista de enteros en haskell

Tags: haskell

tengo esta lista

```
["0 1 1 0","1 0 1 0","1 1 0 1","0 0 1 0"]
```

y quiero convertir cada posición de esa lista en una lista de enteros es decir

```
[[0110],[1010],[1101],[0010]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
intmap :: [String] -> [[Int]]
intmap x = map (\l -> map read (words l)) x
```

Desgranando el código:
`intmap` recibe una lista de Strings y retorna una lista de listas de enteros.
la función lambda `\l ->  map read (words l)` acepta un String y lo convierte a una lista de elementos separada por espacios, para después convertir cada elemento a un entero. Esta función se aplica a cada elemento de la lista con `map`.

La función puede fallar si las strings no representan un entero.Para expandirlo podrían utilizarse excepciones o la mónada Maybe.

Comment: me equivoque en la entrada es ["0 1 0 1"] osea hay un espacio entre los números como se haría en ese caso?

Comment: @Efrainrodc Edito la respuesta para responder a este caso. Por favor edita la pregunta para que quede claro cual es el problema y en futuras búsquedas pueda ser útil

Comment: listo, disculpa me falto poner la entrada como era, es con un espacio entre los números 1 0 1 0

Comment: @Efrainrodc no queda claro si quieres que cada uno de los números sea un elemento en la lista o quieres que la lista interior tan sólo conste de un elemento. Por la estructura del resultado parece que es lo segundo, ya que de otra manera las listas tan sólo constarían de un elemento.

Comment: si exacto es [1,0,1,0] gracias